# Play Framework version 2.6/2.7 set PLAY_SESSION cookie to SameSite=None; Secure

Tags: scala, google-chrome, cookies, playframework, samesite

There's many posts confirming that play supports the `SameSite=None; Secure` requirement. However when configuring the session through config like this:

```
    ...
    play.http.session.httpOnly=true
    play.http.session.sameSite="None"
    play.http.session.secure=true
    ...
```

Chrome tells me that None is not getting set. See below:
[image: samesitecookie]

To validate I'm on the right back-ported version(2.6.24) I implemented a filter to set other cookies I have control over and when I construct a cookie manually like this:

```
   Cookie(
      key,
      value,
      secure = true,
      sameSite = Some(Cookie.SameSite.None)
    )
```

Chrome will show that `SameSite=None; Secure` does get set on those cookies. Which makes me think there's something with the config implementation that is not understanding `None` the play docs indicate you can only pass `Strict` or `Lax` as well but I was hoping that was just a documentation error.

EDIT: Confirmed cbley answer 2.6.25 works see below screen shot
[image]

Comment: According to https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/10433 this should be fixed in Play 2.7.5

Comment: Does 2.7.5 introduce additional config parsing changes? I validated that 2.6.24 has the "None" added to Cookie.SameSite.

Comment: For 2.6.24 I receive `p.a.h.HttpConfiguration - Assuming play.http.session.sameSite = null, since "None" is not a valid SameSite value (Strict, Lax)` in the console.

Comment: With 2.6.25, it works.

Comment: Yea I was refering when you set cookies `.withCookies` using Cookie.SameSite.None the None enum exists in 2.6.24 but looks like not integrated with config until 2.6.25 which was the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Play versions 2.6.25 and 2.7.5.